# SED manipulation on if condition / regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

```
images:
  image1:
    name: image1
    tag: VERSION
  image2:
    name: image2
    tag: latest
  image3:
    name: image3
    tag: VERSION
  image4:
    name: image4
    tag: latest
```

Hi Guys

I have a small issue, as a part of SED command, I want to find image4 and replace the next line tag with a numerical version but only if the tag is not VERSION. I am using this command

```
sed '/name: image4/{!b;n;s/tag:.*/tag:NEW STRING/}' values.yaml
```

The command I am currently using is looking for image4 and replaces the next line tag: "latest" with "NEW STRING", but if I search for image3 I don't want to replace tag: VERSION with anything, just keep searching until tag: is all but not VERSION.

Thank you

/Vin

Comment: Use AWK, or an actual YAML parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
newversion="1.2.3"  # example of the replacement
sed "/name: image4/{n;/tag: VERSION/!{s/tag:.*/tag: $newversion/;};}" values.yaml
```

Result:

```
  image1:
    name: image1
    tag: VERSION
  image2:
    name: image2
    tag: latest
  image3:
    name: image3
    tag: VERSION
  image4:
    name: image4
    tag: 1.2.3
```

**[EDIT]**

If you want to make an exact match of `name`, excluding a name with
some trailing suffix after `image4`, please try the following:

```
sed '/name: image4$/{n;/tag: VERSION/!{s/tag:.*/tag: NEWSTRING/;};}' values.yaml
```

values.yaml:

```
images:
  image1:
    name: image1
    tag: VERSION
  image2:
    name: image2
    tag: latest
  image3:
    name: image4-blahblah
    tag: latest
  image4:
    name: image4
    tag: latest
```

result:

```
images:
  image1:
    name: image1
    tag: VERSION
  image2:
    name: image2
    tag: latest
  image3:
    name: image4-blahblah
    tag: latest
  image4:
    name: image4
    tag: NEWSTRING
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Tshiono, I have tried it, throws an error "-bash: !{s/tag: event not found".

Comment: Hello Tshiono, I have fixed, it is working very well, just change the double quotes to single.

Comment: now, I have new challenge for you, what if name of image3 will be images4-blahblahb. and tag would be something else but not VERSION, - it will swap that tag as well. Can we much exact name?

Comment: @vinilka8 Good to know its working. The behavior of `!` within the `sed` command related to the quoting seems to differ across the environment. Your tweak will make sense. As of your additional requirement, I've updated my answer. I hope it will meet your requirements. BR.

Comment: Hi Tshiono, Thank you for this great help.

Comment: @vinilka8 My pleasure.

Comment: Hi Tshiono, I need you help again. for example I have Dockerfile where in the top I have ARG BLUE_SKY=1.23 and ARG BLUE_SKY_IMAGE_NAME=blue_sky. how to use sed to swap the value only from BLUE_SKY, I need to much all name in version only.

Comment: @vinilka8 Thank you for the message. But I suppose your new requirement looks unrelated to your original post. Would you please create a new question (thread) with your input, desired output, and hopefully your effort for it? Then I'd be happy to answer it. (Others may answer, of course.) Sorry for the inconvenience. BR.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v num="2.03" -F: '/name/ {
                               nam=$2
                              } 
                      /tag/ { 
                              tag=$2;
                              if(nam==" image4" && tag!=" VERSION") { 
                                    print "    tag: "num
                              } 
                              else { 
                                    print $0
                              } 
                            }                 
                      !/tag/ { 
                               print $0 
                             }' images
```

Assuming the data is in a file called images.

Using awk, use -v to first pass the version number required as a variable - num. Use -F to set the delimiter : Parse each line, checking for tag and name. If name is found, set the variable nam, if tag is found, set the variable tag. Further check to see if nam equals " image4" and tag is not equal to VERSION. If  this is the case, print the version number (num) otherwise just print the line ($0) For all other line parsing, print the line ($0)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the right tool for the task and pick a real yml parser. Python 3 needs a third party library but Ruby has yml support baked in.

You can use this script to achieve what you want :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'yaml'
obj = YAML.load_file('input.yml')

obj['images'].each do |k,v|
    obj['images'][k]['tag'] = "WHATEVERYOUWANT" if obj['images'][k]['name'] == "image4" && obj['images'][k]['tag'] != "VERSION"
end

puts YAML.dump(obj)
```

Output :

```
 $ ./yml_parse.rb 
---
images:
  image1:
    name: image1
    tag: VERSION
  image2:
    name: image2
    tag: latest
  image3:
    name: image3
    tag: VERSION
  image4:
    name: image4
    tag: WHATEVERYOUWANT
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Matias, great Idea, but when dumping into the file, it removes all white spaces and adds "---" on the top of the file. I am working around it now, hope will find the solution to leave files as it is but change only what I need. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @vinilka8 I think it's simply writing with the right format for yml syntax.